# Enable scroll in Modal Popup Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using a Modal view to display image in popup view, but there is no scroll feature and I want to add it, can anyone help with code?

Script:

```
<script>
// Get the modal
var modal3 = document.getElementById('myModal3');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img3 = $('.myImg3');
var modalImg3 = $("#img03");
var captionText3 = document.getElementById("caption3");
$('.myImg3').click(function(){
    modal3.style.display = "block";
    var newSrc3 = this.src;
    modalImg3.attr('src', newSrc3);
    captionText3.innerHTML = this.alt;
});

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("clos")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal3.style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<img style="height:100px;" class="myImg3" src='<?php echo "uploads/" . $patient_pre['img_url']; ?>'>
                
    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModal3" class="modal">
    
      <!-- The Close Button -->
      <span class="clos" onclick="document.getElementById('myModal3').style.display='none'">&times;</span>
    
      <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
      <img class="modal-content" id="img03">
    
      <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
      <div id="caption3"></div>
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Generally it is just a two div process, your main wrap (fixed sizing) and your content. On overflow scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `overflow-y: auto;` to the modal's body:

```
<div id="myModal3" class="modal" style="overflow-y: auto;">
```